# Is it possible to run roles that are defined in the site.yml asynchronously in Ansible without opening thousand terminals?

Tags: ansible

At the moment multiple roles have been defined in the site.yml:

```
- include: role1.yml
- include: role2.yml
- include: role3.yml
- include: role4.yml
- include: role5.yml
```

and these are run synchronously by issuing:

```
ansible-playbook -i testing site.yml -u root --vault-password-file ~/.vault_pass.txt
```

**Question**

How to run the defined roles in the site.yml all at once?

**Discussion**

It works to run all roles asynchronously by opening multiple terminals and run:

```
ansible-playbook -i testing playbook1.yml -u root --vault-password-file ~/.vault_pass.txt
ansible-playbook -i testing playbook2.yml -u root --vault-password-file ~/.vault_pass.txt
ansible-playbook -i testing playbook3.yml -u root --vault-password-file ~/.vault_pass.txt
ansible-playbook -i testing playbook4.yml -u root --vault-password-file ~/.vault_pass.txt
ansible-playbook -i testing playbook5.yml -u root --vault-password-file ~/.vault_pass.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [playbooks strategies](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_strategies.html):

> In 2.0 we added a new way to control play execution, strategy, by default plays will still run as they used to, with what we call the linear strategy. All hosts will run each task before any host starts the next task, using the number of forks (default 5) to parallelize.

It is worth a try to set strategy to `free`:

> A second strategy ships with ansible free, which allows each host to run until the end of the play as fast as it can.

```
- hosts: all
  strategy: free
```

Also check the [forks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#forks) setting in `ansible.cfg`:

> This is the default number of parallel processes to spawn when communicating with remote hosts. Since Ansible 1.3, the fork number is automatically limited to the number of possible hosts, so this is really a limit of how much network and CPU load you think you can handle. Many users may set this to 50, some set it to 500 or more. If you have a large number of hosts, higher values will make actions across all of those hosts complete faster. The default is very very conservative:

```
forks=5
```

Comment: I have added the hosts and strategy to the site.yml, but ansible still deploys on one host at a time